# How are image(jpeg and png) files formatted within SVG files?

Tags: javascript, image, svg

I am attempting to edit an SVG file in JS, I have already developed a method for doing so. I am struggling on how to change the image, which is a jpeg, in said file. In the SVG before I made any edits it contained a huge string of letters that translated into the image.

Here is a chunk of that.

```
CQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSEx BhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElK U1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYa
```

If you open a jpeg file in a text editor you also get a string of seemingly random characters, however putting these into the SVG does not make the desired image appear. The text that corresponds the image is filled with question marks in diamonds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's [base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). It almost certainly already tells you that in the xlink:href attribute. I.e. I expect it looks something like this:
 xlink:href="data:image/png;**base64**,..."

You'd need to [base64 encode](https://www.base64encode.org/) the jpeg before you paste the resultant characters into the [data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

Comment: Thanks, now I know what the encryption is called and can do all the research I need for it to be applied to my project. Thanks, again!

Comment: There's no encryption here, only encoding.